# A Counting problem related with Combination

Tags: combinatorics

1) Find the number m of ways that 12 student can be partitioned into 3 teams T1,T2,T3 so that each contain 4 students ?

2)There are 12 students in a class .Find the number n of ways that 12 studemts can take 3 different tests if 4 students take each test ?

#### Please Help

Answer (score 2):

We first choose the group player $1$ belongs to.  This can be done in $\binom{11}{3}$ ways.  We next choose the group that the lowest indexed remaining player belongs to, this can be done in $\binom{7}{3}$ ways.  The remaining players form the other group.  This gives $\binom{11}{3}\binom{7}{3}=5775$ ways.

Alternatively, we can fill in the groups like this:  $$\big\{\{1,2,3,4\},\{5,6,7,8\},\{9,10,11,12\}\big\}$$ and permute the numbers ($12!$ ways).  Two arrangements are equivalent if the permutation permutes players within a group ($4!^3$ ways), or permutes the groups as a whole ($3!$ ways).  This gives $\frac{12!}{4!^3 3!}=5775$ ways.

In response to the second part, if the tests taken distinguish the groups, then we multiply the last answer by $3!$.

Comment: Please Rebecca Can you Explain The Alternative Part In different Manner .

Comment: The second version uses the idea of group actions (the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem).  If we write down all $12!$ orderings of the numbers in the brackets.  Some of them will describe the same grouping.  E.g. $\{\{4,3,2,1\},\{5,6,7,8\},\{9,10,11,12\}\}$ and $\{\{5,6,7,8\},\{1,2,3,4\},\{9,10,11,12\}\}$ describe the same grouping as the one above.  Two ways to achieve this: permuting elements within a group ($4!$ ways to do this per group), or permuting the groups as a whole ($3!$ ways we can do this).  Other permutations will "break" the groups.  Each grouping therefore will appear $4!^3 3!$ times.

Answer (score 1):

For the first team, students can be selected in $\binom{12}{4}$ ways, for the second team, we have $\binom{8}{4}$ choices. The remaining kids go to the third team.

The number of ways is thus $\binom{12}{4} * \binom{8}{4}$.

Since there is nothing special about the group that you pick, we need to discount by $3!$, giving the final answer $(\binom{12}{4} * \binom{8}{4}) / 3!$.

Comment: Answer :5775 But according to You It Evaluate : 34,650

Comment: @Rijubose  The quotient $$\frac{\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}}{3!} = 5775$$

Comment: yes I got It but what about next part ?